# LDAP Distinguished name contains apostrophe in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ldap-query

I am running a procedure to get the security groups of a user from LDAP.
I am using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN to check if the DN is a member.
Here is my query :

```
SET @Query = '
    SELECT cn,AdsPath
    FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ''<'+@adspath+'>;(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' +@Path+'));cn, adspath;subtree'')'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

@path contains a DN : CN=Jim O'Brien,OU=Managed,OU=Accounts,DC=willeke,DC=com

There is an error while I run the procedure :
**Incorrect syntax near 'Brien'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.**

Procedure executes successfully for other users. I have only problems with apostrophe in the distinguished name.

I know if I use replace function to remove apostrophe for both sides where I compare the values it will work. But How do I use it on the LHS i.e (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941)

Looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QUOTENAME` or `REPLACE` to safely escape the value:

```sql
SET @Query = '
    SELECT cn,AdsPath
    FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ''<'+REPLACE(@adspath,'''','''''')+'>;(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' +REPLACE(@Path,'''','''''')+'));cn, adspath;subtree'')'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Query;
```

Considering you aren't wrapping the value in single quotes (`'`) here, then `REPLACE` seems the better option.

---

Edit, as the OP is struggling the read the entire line, I assume due to the horizontal scroll bar, note that I escape **both** variables, using `REPLACE`: `+REPLACE(@adspath,'''','''''')` *and* `REPLACE(@Path,'''','''''')`. This will mean any single quotes(`'`) will be "doubled up" to `''` and therefore safely escaped.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I need to replace apostrophe in "member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941" and not in adspath variable

Comment: @sourabhshinde check again, i escaped **both** variables...

Comment: I don't want to replace strings in adspath variable . I want something like this. REPLACE(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941,'''','''''') := REPLACE(@path,'''','''''')

Comment: ... @sourabhshinde again, I escaped **both**. That's `@adspath` and `@Path`... Please take the time to read the entire answer.

Comment: Yes I read your entire answer. But I don't have any string with apostrophe in adspath variable. I just have it in path variable. If I remove apostrophe from this variable using replace it doesn't match with LHS side i.e member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941

Comment: Just because `@path` doesn't have a single quote (`'`) in it's current value doesn't mean it won't. You should **always** safely quote, or escape your values when you inject them into dynamic SQL, @sourabhshinde, *always*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep this in mind for future. But still doesn't solve my problem